# Gerar PDF de uma pagina HTML (contendo imagem) Utilizando html2pdf

Tags: html2pdf-js

Estou tentando gerar pdf de uma pagina html porem dá o erro: ml2canvas.js:2424 1878014a704 248ms Error loading image.

Essa pagina contem uma imagem, é ela que está causando o erro, quanto tento gerar o pdf sem a imagem ele funciona normalmente, mas preciso gerar com essa imagem.

```
<div id="content">

   <div>
     
      <img src="image.jpeg">

      <span>

         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
         
      </span>

   </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')

  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {

        // conteudo 
  const content = document.querySelector('#content');

   //configuração 
            
    const options = {

      margin: [10, 10, 10 ,10],
      filename: "arquivo.pdf",
      html2canvas: {scale: 2},
      image: {type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98},
      jsPDF: {unit: "mm", format: "a4", orientation: "portrait"}
}   

//gerar e baixar pdf 

      html2pdf().set(options).from(content).save();
});

</script>
```

Tentei converter em base64 mas não deu certo.